# set margin-left of a div according to the width of that div, which is set in percentage

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` that has a width of `65%`, according to the size of my screen. This div should be hidden at all time, with a negative `margin-left` equal to the width of that div, and it appears when the user clicks on a certain button.

I am working with a `1309px` screen width. I started by setting `width` of the `div` according to the size of my screen, which means that the `width` of the `div` was `860px`, and to hide it, i set a `margin-left:-860px`.

CSS

```
#left{

left:0%;
margin-left:-990px;
width:65.7%;
height:100%;
margin-top:80px;
float:left;
position:fixed;
background:#fff;
margin-top:160px !important;
}
```

How can I do it to dynamically set the margin left according to the width of my div?

Comment: Would `margin-left:-65.7%;` work?

Comment: wow i am embarassed to say it worked, and it was that easy! I didn't know using percentages with margins was possible! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Set the margin to `margin-left:-65.7%;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide something and later show it just use

```
display: none
```

in your CSS and then change the visibility through Javascript when the button is clicked

```
document.getElementById('element').style.display = "block";
```

or jQuery, if you're using that

```
$("#element").css("display", "block");
```